# How do I wrap the text while entering into an Html.TextBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

The markup below is what I have right now. I am writing an MVC application.
I found advise on this site that lead me to insert the width and height, however that did not answer my problem.
When I am entering text that is longer that 500px I want it to wrap, currently it is all staying on a single line and obviously, the complete text is not visible.
Can anyone help?

### Thanks

Describe your Special:
            
            
            
            <%= Html.TextBox("ShortDescription", Model.Special.ShortDescription, new { @style = "width: 500px; height:60px;background-color:#f1f2f3" })%>

Answer (score 4):

The `Html.TextBox` helper generates an `<input type="text" ...` and text inside this type of inputs doesn't wrap. You should consider using a `<textarea>`. You could use the `Html.TextAreaFor` helper (not `Html.TextArea` because you already have a model, so make profit from it):

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Special.ShortDescription, 10, 20, 
    new { @style = "background-color: #f1f2f3" }) %>
```

Comment: +1. Good point Darin - I completely neglected using the model. :P

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a TextArea as such:

```
<%= Html.TextArea("ShortDescription", Model.Special.ShortDescription) %>
```

or for your case explicitly :

```
<%= Html.TextArea("ShortDescription", Model.Special.ShortDescription, 
    new { @style = "width: 500px; height:60px;background-color:#f1f2f3" })%>
```

Comment: Thank you...that did it and I feel a little ridiculous

Comment: No problem Steve, we all run into things that make us feel that way on a day-to-day basis :)